# Change background-color in php using text input form

Tags: php, background-color

I write a program that changes the background color of a page via a form using a text input field. I am trying to assign a variable to whatever value is written in the text field.

The code works when the input value `!= 6` however when input value `== 6` it does not work. I think the problem arises when I try to assign the value entered into the text field to `$color` in the `activity1.php` file.

activity1.php

```
<?php
$color = "color";
if (isset ($_POST["button1"])) {
    if (strlen($_POST["color"]) == 6) {
        echo "<body style='background:#$color;'>";
    } elseif (strlen($_POST["color"]) != 6) {
        echo "Please enter a valid 6 digit hex code<body style='background: black; color: white;'><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

pageColor.php

```
<body>
<form action="pageColor.php" method="post">
    <?php
    include "activity1.php";
    ?>
    Please enter your color code: <input type="text" id="color" name="color" />
    <input type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Two `body` tags in a page is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as hinted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167312/change-background-color-in-php-using-text-input-form#comment30063372_20167312) comment is that you are outputting two body tags. This is not valid html.

To address this, I prefer to have separate html and php code, so that I can process the html with php, and also have a clear view of my html code.

body.html:

```
<body style="background-color:{zBackgroundColor}">
<form action="pageColor.php" method="post">
    Please enter your color code: <input type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" />
    <p>{zErrorContainer}</p>
    <input type="submit" id="button1" name="button1">
</form>
</body>
```

In the php code, I only have the logic containing the values to be replaced in the html:

```
$color = '#FFFFFF'; // that way your values won't be undefined when the post is not submitetd
$error = '';
if (isset ($_POST["button1"])) {
    if (strlen($_POST["color"]) == 6) {
        $color = $_POST['color'];
        $error = '';
    } else { // no need to verify length two times
        $color = '';
        $error = 'Please specify a correct color value';
    }
}
$data = [
    '{zBackgroundColor}' => $color,
    '{zErrorContainer}' => $error,
]
```

I like using [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace values in my html. there are other functions to replace content in strings, such as [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), which is more powerful and faster, but a bit more constraining and complicated

```
$html= strtr(file_get_contents('body.html'), $data);
echo $html;
```

The values contained in the `$data` will replace the placeholders in the template. The {z} brackets are important as `strtr()` will replace any string that matches any key of your array with it's value. Having those brackets with the 'z' letter minimizes the possibilities of it replacing an unwanted string.

---

however, directly accessing values in your `$_POST` is somewhat dangerous, as it has no control over what is sent to your server. Consider at least using [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

```
$color = filter_input(\INPUT_POST, 'color', \FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Answer (score -1):

First I would not suggest what you are trying because that can easily be and should be done with Javascript but as you said you are just learning so here are your errors.

```
//First there are 2 body tags which is totally wrong. your php page should be like this
```

activity.php

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_POST["button1"]))
     {
       //Checking for lenght and hexa type
       if(ctype_xdigit($_POST["color"]) && (strlen($_POST["color"]) == 6 || strlen($_POST["color"]) == 3)) 
       {
        echo  '<body style=\'background-color:#'.$_POST["color"].';\'>';
       } 
       elseif(!ctype_xdigit($_POST["color"]) || (strlen($_POST["color"]) != 6 && strlen($_POST["color"]) != 3))
       {
        echo "Please enter a valid 6 or 3 digit hex code<br /><body style='background-color: black; color: white;'><br />";
        }
      }
?>
```

pageColor.php

```
<?php
    include "activity1.php";
?>
    <form action="pageColor.php" method="post">

    Please enter your color code:<input type="text" id="color" name="color" />
    <input type="submit" id="button1" name="button1" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please comment why someone gave -1

Comment: here it is. IN your code,the $color value is always "Red".so the background will be always red,irrespective of what the user enters.you are not using the posted value $_POST['color']

Comment: ha ha ha. If you are so jealous u could have checked your answer before posting.LOL

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Jquery?

http://api.jquery.com/css/

You can change the background color on submission.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#form").submit(function()
{
    $("body").css({"background-color": "#Code"});
})

})
```

You can retrieve the input element by giving it an id and

```
$("#elem").val();
```

The example above will also require you to assign an ID to the form.

For your code;

Try: `echo  '<body style="background:#'.$color;.'">'';`

Answer (score -1):

after this loop

```
if (strlen($_POST["color"]) == 6){
```

you are not assigning $color value to $_POST['color']. so the variable color value will remain as "color".when u are using in styling `"background:#color"` is not valid css.

```
$color = "color";
if (isset ($_POST["button1"])){
    if (strlen($_POST["color"]) == 6){
        // $color value is color here. '#color' is not a proper hex bg code. 
        echo  "<body style='background:#$color;'>";
    }elseif(strlen($_POST["color"]) != 6){
    echo "Please enter a valid 6 digit hex code<body style='background: black; color: white;'><br>";
    }
}
```

try changing this to

```
$color = "color";
if (isset ($_POST["button1"])){
    if (strlen($_POST["color"]) == 6){
        $color=$_POST["color"];
        echo  "<body style='background:#$color;'>";
    }elseif(strlen($_POST["color"]) != 6){
    echo "Please enter a valid 6 digit hex code<body style='background: black; color: white;'><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was excellent and it did work fine. I am just learning to use this site and I was not aware that one can be marked up or down. I meant to mark it as correct. I will fix it as soon as I can. Once again my apologies.